# Creating UIImage from data stored as Blob on MySQL server

Tags: php, swift, uiimage

**EDIT 2:**

For anyone that comes across this, I did a workaround that ended up working. I'm not entirely sure why (which is why I didn't post it as an answer), and if anyone wants to chime in I'd be happy to learn, but here's the solution I came up with:

After getting the responseData from the server, I converted it to a string using:

```
let string = String(data: responseData, encoding: .utf8)!
```

(I force-unwrapped it for ease and testing, but I'd probably optionally bind it in a final build)

And then I re-converted it to Data using Swift's method:

```
let data = Data(base64Encoded: string)
```

Once I put this into the UIImage, it actually worked perfectly fine!

I'm assuming that there is a difference in the way that PHP and Swift encode things? Or Swift needs it to be further processed or something? Whatever the reason, that worked. So hopefully that can help someone else!

---

**Original Question**

I have an image stored on a MySQL server as a blob. When the image is uploaded, it's encoded in base64 using PHP's

```
base64_encode()
```

function.

This produces a long string that looks something like this (EDIT: It ends up being something like 200,000 bytes, so I put the whole thing here at https://pastebin.com/bDw2hca5)

```
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...
```

I'm then using a typical network call in Swift, and simply returning the data that comes from the response:

```
    func getImages(iD: Int, completed: @escaping (Result<Data, Error>) -> Void) {
    let urlString = "https://example.com/getImages.php?id=\(iD)"
    
    guard let url = URL(string: urlString) else {
        completed(.failure(ErrorMessages.urlError))
        return
    }
    
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
        
        if let _ = error {
            completed(.failure(ErrorMessages.networkingError))
        }
        
        guard let data = data else {
            completed(.failure(ErrorMessages.dataError))
            return
        }
        
        completed(.success(data))
        
    }
    
    task.resume()
}
```

But when I try to use the data to create a UIImage using

```
UIImage(data: responseData)
```

It just creates a blank screen. (I've also tried adding .base64EncodedData())

What am I doing wrong to make the image just appear as blank? Should I be encoding something differently?

Comment: Maybe with some options in the base64 decoding? I tried to decode your data here https://www.base64decode.org and I got strange result, There is "PNG" at top, and then XML? Maybe a full content of the blob example might be good. Try to upload it maybe elsewhere? Pastebin? Etc.?

Comment: Thanks! I put the encoding up on Pastebin, as maybe that can add more context to the problem. Also, when I took the same image and used swift to get the .pngData() it printed out something similar looking, but it does look like a different length. Maybe PHP base64encode uses a different algorithm?

Comment: Paste bin is not available: "Error, this is a private paste or is pending moderation. If this paste belongs to you, please login to Pastebin to view it."

Comment: Where does a guy named 'responseData' come from?